# How can I split Jquery.js file into multiple file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web server that files must be smaller than 64KB and I have a lot of dependency to jquery and I can't use other library such as zepto.
the jquery minified size is 95Kb and i want split jquery into two files.
how can i split this file into two files?

> NB. I have to use atleast v1.9 or later for my project and the server does not support gzip.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery hosted in a CDN?

Comment: I don't have access to internet and other server

Comment: You're not going to be able to do that. What do you mean when you say you "don't have access to internet and other server"? Using a CDN just means referencing a public repository for the file in the `<script>` tag.

Comment: I have a small server in special device with limit memory! I don't have any public repository and clients don't have access to other server.

Answer (score 3):

Every thing is possible !

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        client.open('GET', '/js/jq1.js',false);
        client.onload = function() {
        var jq1 = client.responseText;
        client.open('GET', '/js/jq2.js',false);
        client.onload = function() {
        var jq2 = client.responseText;
        var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
        scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
        scriptTag.innerHTML = jq1+jq2;
        scriptTag.async = false;
        ( document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement ).appendChild( scriptTag );
}
client.send();
}
client.send();
        </script>
```

Comment: However I think if you are using a device with limited memory, then the jquery library may have a huge amount of overhead you don't need.  There are many other libraries out there that are much smaller that might suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

In this case i would select an older version of jQuery. here you will find the file size of various versions of Jquery as you **can not use CDN**. minified 1.3.2v is less that 64KB it think.

https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/jquery-size